# getting error everytime after using the correct code in atom importing folium

Tags: python, tiles

getting error everytime after using the correct code in atom importing folium. folloing is the screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5IfB.png)

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Though... please read the error message (typed out manually due to the image so excuse typos): "ValueError: Built-in tempates for Mapbox and Cloudmade have been removed. You can still use these providers by passing a URL to the \`tiles\` argument. See the documentation of the `\TileLayer\` class." Be careful when asserting that your code is "correct". Programming errors are almost always in something you have done.